# Issues with GROUP BY and NULL (SQL / BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some bad data that I need to transform a bit and am struggling to do.

Below is example data and desired output.

What I'm hoping for is if PUNCHIN is NULL, but there is another value of PUNCHIN for that EmployeeNum and APPLY_DATE, then use the other value. Otherwise, use SHIFTSTARTTIME. And the same goes for PUNCHOUT and SHIFTENDTIME.

Originally I thought to use MIN(PUNCHIN) and GROUP BY but there can be multiple entries for EmployeeNum and APPLY_DATE, as seen for EmployeeNum 456

````
| EmployeeNum |     APPLY_DATE      |       PUNCHIN       |      PUNCHOUT       |   SHIFTSTARTTIME    |    SHIFTENDTIME     |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         123 | 2019-06-29T00:00:00 | null                | 2019-06-30T00:55:00 | 2019-06-29T17:00:00 | 2019-06-30T01:00:00 |
|         123 | 2019-06-29T00:00:00 | 2019-06-29T16:54:00 | null                | 2019-06-29T17:00:00 | 2019-06-30T01:00:00 |
|         456 | 2019-12-09T00:00:00 | 2019-12-09T16:15:00 | 2019-12-09T21:15:00 | 2019-12-09T16:15:00 | 2019-12-09T21:15:00 |
|         456 | 2019-12-09T00:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 |
|         789 | 2019-12-22T00:00:00 | null                | null                | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+ ```

And the output I'm looking for is:

```+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| EmployeeNum |     APPLY_DATE      |       PUNCHIN       |      PUNCHOUT       |     SHIFTSTART      |      SHIFTEND       |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         123 | 2019-06-29T00:00:00 | 2019-06-29T16:54:00 | 2019-06-30T00:55:00 | 2019-06-29T17:00:00 | 2019-06-30T01:00:00 |
|         456 | 2019-12-09T00:00:00 | 2019-12-09T16:15:00 | 2019-12-09T21:15:00 | 2019-12-09T16:15:00 | 2019-12-09T21:15:00 |
|         456 | 2019-12-09T00:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 |
|         789 | 2019-12-22T00:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 | 2019-12-09T22:00:00 | 2019-12-10T02:00:00 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
select distinct employeenum, apply_date,
       coalesce(punchin, max(punchin) over (partition by employeenum, apply_date), apply_date),
       coalesce(punchout, max(punchout) over (partition by employeenum, apply_date), apply_date)
from t;
```

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know you could OVER PARTITION BY with COALESCE
Would that work for 789 though?

Comment: @rogerlumley88 . . . I added `apply_date` as the third argument to `coalesce()` and that should work.

Comment: I think SHIFTSTARTTIME and SHIFTENDTIME instead of APPLY_DATE

Thanks! This is perfect though